# Looking for word parsing web site that tells if a word is a Noun, Verb, etc

Tags: xml, dictionary, web, nlp

Is there a web site I can call that will allow me to send it a word and it will tell me if that word is a Noun, Verb, etc. ?

I'm hoping to find that kind of site that maybe would return xml that I can use to parse out the returned results.

Thanks.

Comment: As an alternative solution you could use a website like this: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/helicopter, passing the word in as part of the URL and then parse the resulting HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will need to find out how to parse HTML. In the mean time do you know of something like that site that returns XML results?

Comment: No and I couldn't find anything on Google either. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for at dictionary.com because they have an API that returns XML code.

Here's the link:
http://developer.dictionary.com

Hopefully this will help other people out there looking to do the same as I.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a web service. If your target language is English, then use [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). It has bindings for many popular programming languages.

Note that many words are ambiguous wrt. their category; finding the right one in context is a problem known as part-of-speech (POS) tagging and is usually done using machine-learned algorithms. Various free POS taggers are available, including the [Stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) one.

(If you desperately want a web service and XML, you can hack that onto WordNet :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for XML results because I making an Android app using Basic4Android and it allows me to parse XML returned results from a web site.

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen: some quick Googling turned up [this project](http://wnws.sourceforge.net/), maybe it can be of use?

Comment: I looked but it uses something I need to download to my pc. As an example I use this to get geocoding information in XML format: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=522%20cleermont%20dr.%20huntsville%20al Maybe there is something out there that does the same with words.

Comment: Minor: I think the first/primary answer should be a POS tagging service, with WordNet as a related resource.